# Соотношение объёма русского и английского текста

Tags: перевод, транслитерация

Недавно в статье наткнулся на такое высказывание Гилберта Доктороу (Gilbert Doctorow):

> Русская версия текста занимает 26 страниц мелким шрифтом. Ею я и пользовался, потому что предпочитаю иметь дело с источником и переводить самостоятельно, если могу. Английский текст занимает 40 страниц, что нормально для перевода с русского. (The Russian version takes up 26 tightly spaced printed pages. This is what I have used, since I prefer to go to the source and do my own translations when I have the option. The English version probably takes 40 pages, given the normal expansion from Russian to English in the translation process.)

Насколько справедливо подобное высказывание? Мне подобное соотношение объёма оригинального и переводного текста показалось странным.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что при переводе текст вообще "разбухает", неважно, переводят ли с русского на английский, или же наоборот.

И дело тут не в длине отдельных слов (английские слова в среднем действительно несколько короче, а если учитывать только слоги - поэтический перевод - то и *намного* короче), что на самом деле компенсируется наличием артиклей и избытком предлогов, а, скорее, необходимостью постоянно "дообъяснять" переведенное. Переводчик вынужден "копировать" не только смысл, но и сам ход рассуждений автора, его "логику", а подыскивать для этого достаточно лаконичные параллели в другом языке, не сбиваясь на длиннющие придаточные предложения, может быть весьма непросто. Так что хотя в идеале перевод должен быть примерно той же длины, что и оригинал, но в реальности перевод оказывается почти всегда длиннее. В особенности это справедливо для "технического" перевода, когда переводчик не слишком заинтересован в сохранении ритмики и метафоричности исходного текста, а просто "пересказывает", что там написано, идя по пути наименьшего сопротивления.

Answer (score 6):

Я присутствовала на лекции С. Л. Николаева (доктор филологических наук, Институт славяноведения РАН), где после лекции был задан этот вопрос. Доктор Николаев ответил, что такой зависимости он не отметил. Перевод обычно длиннее оригинала, так как понятие, передаваемое одним словом в языке А, нередко переводится двумя словами в языке Б, чтобы избавиться от нежелательных оттенков смысла (значений (2), (3) и т. д. в словаре).

О существовании доказательных исследований на этот счёт не знаю.

Answer (score 4):

Я работал переводчиком какое-то довольно непродолжительное время, но тем не менее - из моего опыта русский текст длиннее, в среднем в раза где-то 1.2-1.3. Уверен, что профессиональный переводчик может дать более точную оценку этого коэффициента, но какой бы они ни был - он совершенно точно больше единицы. Русские слова в в среднем длиннее.

**UPD:**
Let's come up with more precise data. According to Wolfram's [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=average%20english%20word%20length) search engine, the average English word is 5.1 characters in length. This is based on an average of several different text bases, including Britannica and Wikipedia.

In terms of Russian, I've seen some different estimates that varied pretty noticeably (from [~5.28](http://www.lingvisto.org/artikoloj/ru_stat.html) to [~9.97](http://www.ravi.io/language-word-lengths)), I guess it heavily depends on the text corpora used for collecting statistics. Also, one should bear in mind that beside the average length of word, we should also take into account the average length of a sentence, which could also be different.

Comment: Мой опыт англо-русского технического перевода подтверждает эти цифры. Интересно, однако, что [вот этот простецкий английский перевод](http://www.paskvil.com/file/files-books/bulgakov-master-and-margarita.pdf) первой главы «Мастера и Маргариты» Булгакова длиннее оригинала на 10% (в буквах). Подозреваю, что хороший перевод может быть ещё длиннее.

Comment: Слышал что средняя длина предложения приблизительно одинакова в разных языках, так как если в русском языке связь слов в предложении и т.п. строится на изменении самих слов (суффиксами, окончаниями и т.п.), то, например в английском (или болгарском), сами слова остаются неизменными, но эту функцию выполняют служебные слова, предлоги и т.п. В общем, задачи языки выполняют похожие, но разными средствами. Из-за этого средняя длина слов может сильно отличаться, но длина предложений более-менее одинакова. (Интересно, впрочем посмотреть на языки с бедной фонетикой: в гавайском напр. только 14 букв).

Answer (score 3):

Выводы, основанные на статистике переводов:

> Примечательно, что при переводе с английского на русский, длина текста вырастает на 9.11%, а при переводе в обратном направлении… снова вырастает, но всего на 1.39%. Это может говорить о том, что переводчики используют больше слов, чтобы не потерять и передать смысл текста правильно в ущерб лаконичности.

Источник: статья [на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/company/alconost/blog/197146/).

Но как учесть размер шрифта?
На лист А4 у меня влезло
52 строчки размера 12 пунктов,
62 строчки размера 10 пунктов,
69 строчек размера 9 пунктов,
77 строчек размера 8 пунктов.
Если «мелкий шрифт» имеет размер 8 пунктов, а английский перевод — 12 пунктов, то получаем (77/52)*26 = 38,5 страниц такого же текста, написанного крупным шрифтом вместо мелкого.
Тогда перевод добавляет полторы страницы к 38.5 страницам. Нормальное соотношение.
Единственное, чего я не знаю — насколько принято в английском пользоваться размером 12 пунктов.

**Upd.** Вычисления, основанные на количестве строк на странице, учитывают только высоту букв. Но ведь при изменении размера шрифта изменяется и ширина букв, то есть на одну строку помещается больше текста!

Дальнейшие эксперименты показали:
Если взять 10 страниц, заполненных шрифтом 8 пунктов, и поменять размер шрифта на 10 пунктов, то они превращаются в 15 с половиной страниц (половина измерена на глаз :)).
В такой пропорции 26 страниц шрифтом в 8 пунктов превращается в (26/10)*15.5 = 40.3 (примерно) страниц, напечатанных шрифтом 10 пунктов.
То есть если «мелкий шрифт» имеет размер 8 пунктов, а английский перевод — 10 пунктов, то перевод имеет приблизительно такую же или чуть меньшую длину в буквах, чем оригинал.